# Copy page blob from one storage account to Another storage account using .Net API startCopy

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to copy a page blob in one storage account to another storage account using .net API startCopy. Both storage accounts are standard type and blob exists in source location. I am getting "cannotverifysourcepath" error with below exception details.

I was hoping that startcopy API works to copy from account to another. Can anyone please help me to figure out what's the issue here?

```
Exception- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.StartCopy(Uri source, AccessCondition sourceAccessCondition, AccessCondition destAccessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudPageBlob.StartCopy(CloudPageBlob source, AccessCondition sourceAccessCondition, AccessCondition destAccessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
Request Information
RequestID:1a82f5b6-0001-008f-7328-26bec1000000
RequestDate:Fri, 14 Oct 2016 14:35:31 GMT
StatusMessage:The specified resource does not exist.
ErrorCode:CannotVerifyCopySource
```

Comment: All you included is your stack trace, not the actual call you made. Please edit to show how you're calling `StartCopy()`. (obviously obscure the real storage account name / key). Also, please clarify how you confirmed the source path is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the [data movement library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement). Specifically:

```
await TransferManager.CopyAsync(source, target, false);
```

The boolean parameter specifies whether or not this is a service-side asynchronous copy. If it is, the local task may complete before the copy is complete.

I have verified that this works when `source` and `target` are in different accounts and both access policies are 'private.'

Answer (score 1):

For copying blob across storage accounts, source blob must be publicly accessible. Please check the ACL on the source blob container and see if it is `Private`.

If the source blob container's ACL is `Private`, there are two possible solutions:

1. Create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` on the source blob with at least `Read` permission and an expiry date of at least 15 days and use that SAS URL (blob URL + SAS token) as copy source.
2. Not recommended, but you can change the ACL of the source blob container to `Blob`. This will make the source blob publicly accessible. Your code should work as is in that case.