# Unable to copy blob from one storage account to another

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to copy a blob from one Azure storage account to another storage account (same subscription) but I get an exception:

> The specified resource does not exist.

As I've realised, the problem is caused by the container being set to `Private`, which is what it should be for our business purposes.

I've taken my cue from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40054739/262892) which suggests:

> Create a Shared Access Signature (SAS) on the source blob with at least Read permission and an expiry date of at least 15 days and use that SAS URL (blob URL + SAS token) as copy source.

Furthermore, I've found some code on the [Microsoft forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0b5e7814-d0df-41fa-b6dc-2439c730986b/how-to-use-copy-blob-usng-sas?forum=windowsazuredata) from the same poster where he posts code that worked for him. From that, I now have the following code (`ct` is a `CancellationToken`):

```
var snapshot = await blob.CreateSnapshotAsync(ct);
var sourceSAS = snapshot.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy {
                                                                                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                                                                                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                                                                                SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(-1)
                                                                            });
var sourceUri = $"{snapshot.Uri}{sourceSAS}";

var backupBlob = FileBackupContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);
var targetSAS = backupBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy {
                                                                                  Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write,
                                                                                  SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
                                                                                  SharedAccessStartTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddHours(-1)
                                                                              });
var targetUri = $"{backupBlob.Uri}{targetSAS}";

var newTargetBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(targetUri));
await newTargetBlob.StartCopyAsync(new Uri(sourceUri), ct);

await snapshot.DeleteAsync(ct);
```

But I still encounter the same exception.

What more do I need in order to copy a blob using its SAS?

**UPDATE:**
My code wasn't working because the source blob was in my local storage emulator (*i.e.* localhost) which is obviously inaccessible to the target storage container which is Azure-hosted.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question...

My code wasn't working because the source blob was in my local storage emulator (i.e. localhost) which is obviously inaccessible to the target storage container which is Azure-hosted.